# Heroku Multi-Factor Authentication Your identity couldn't be verified

Tags: macos, google-chrome, heroku, safari, multi-factor-authentication

Got stuck at - Heroku: Two-Factor Authentication: Your identity couldn't be verified. please let me know how can access my account or bypass the 2FA. I'm not logged in any other devices. Found no credentials on this device" while trying to login in safari.
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I recently read that 2FA was deprecated since spring 2021 and allegedly it was replaced by MFA (multi-factor authentication). I think somebody already asked this question on StackOverflow, this means the problem is probably on Heroku's side and they should fix it, they messed up

Comment: did you found any soln.